# Get All Rows When Variable Empty PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

```
$frame_type = '';

$ret = mysqli_query($con, "select * from products where status='1' AND frame_type = '$frame_type' ");

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }
```

Get All Rows If The $frame_type Is Empty I am trying this way but i get zero rows , How to fix that Where $frame_type has value then send to query else not

Comment: Use an `if` statement so you execute a query without the `frame_type` test when the variable is empty. Why isn't this obvious?

Answer (score -1):

There are a some of things that is wrong with your question (code). But if you only want answer. Just copy this

```
$frame_type = '';

$query = "select * from products where status='1' ";
// strlen has value
if(strlen($frame_type)) {
  $query .= "AND frame_type = '$frame_type'";
}

$ret = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
```

PS: It's never a safe idea to pass everything to the query. Use prepared statement if you can.